# Does windows log which admin domain user authorised an event

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-8, windows-server-2008, active-directory

For example, if a standard user wanted to perform a software installation which would require admin rights, then admin credentials would have to be used to authorize the action. So does windows or active directory keep a log of the admin account that was used to authorize the installation? If so, where would you look to get the information?

Note: The active directory service is running on Windows Server 2008, clients are mainly Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Windows can log logon events, though by default this is not turned on.

Comment: look in eventvwr.exe in the security log, for success audits of event 4624. those are logins. you can check the logintype enum to determine what kind of login it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uac Auditing is done by changing windows policy (Local\Group). The policy in interest is found at: Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy

Audit Privilege Use will give you information about elevated usage using the UAC consent.exe dialog box in the System Event log. The Event IDs created by this: 4648 and 4624.

Audit Process Tracking will give you information about processes and their creation/termination. Event Id created by this: 4688.

Also, look at event id 4696 to see when a new token (user-logon handle) was assigned to process. Using all these events, you can get a clear picture of the timeline for every process that requested an elevated rights with UAC dialog.